# 3D - Variational Autoencoder implementation Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

I'm trying to implement a 3D variational autoencoder following instructions in the book Generative Deep Learning and taking also some things from here [link](https://github.com/bnsreenu/python_for_microscopists/blob/master/178_179_variational_autoencoders_mnist.py), those examples are in 2D so I have adapted it.

This is the code i'm using:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, BatchNormalization, Conv3D, Dense, Flatten, Lambda, Reshape, UpSampling3D
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l2
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

## Functional API

input_shape = (32, 32, 32, 1)
z_dim = 3000 

###########  Encoder  ############

enc_in = Input(shape = input_shape, name="encoder_input")

enc_conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(filters=8, kernel_size=5, strides=(1,1,1), padding='same', activation="ReLU", kernel_initializer="he_uniform", name="conv_1")(enc_in)  
max1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=(2,2,2), strides=(2,2,2), padding='valid', name="max_pool_1")(enc_conv1) 

enc_conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation="ReLU", kernel_initializer="he_uniform", name="conv_2")(max1)
max2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=2, name="max_pool_2")(enc_conv2)

enc_fc1 = Dense(units = 512, kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform', activation = 'ReLU')(Flatten()(max2))
   
mu = Dense(units = z_dim, kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform', activation = None, name="mu")(enc_fc1)
   
log_variance = Dense(units = z_dim, kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform', activation = None, name="log_variance")(enc_fc1)   

def sampling(args):
    mu, log_variance = args
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=K.shape(mu), mean= 0., stddev= 1.)
    return mu + K.exp(0.5 * log_variance) * epsilon

z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape = (z_dim, ), name="z")([mu, log_variance]) 

encoder = Model(enc_in, [mu, log_variance, z], name="encoder")


##########  Decoder  ############

dec_in = Input(shape = (z_dim, ), name="decoder_input")

dec_fc1 = Dense(units = 512, kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform', activation = 'ReLU')(dec_in)
dec_unflatten = Reshape(target_shape = (8,8,8,1))(dec_fc1)

dec_conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation="ReLU", kernel_initializer="he_uniform", name="deconv_1")(dec_unflatten)
ups1 = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling3D(size=(2, 2, 2), name="ups_1")(dec_conv1)

dec_conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation="ReLU", kernel_initializer="he_uniform", name="deconv_2")(ups1)
ups2 = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling3D(size=(2, 2, 2), name="ups_2")(dec_conv2)

dec_conv4 = Conv3D(filters = 1, kernel_size = (3, 3, 3), padding = 'same', activation="ReLU", kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform', name='decorder_output')(ups2)

decoder = Model(dec_in, dec_conv4, name="decoder")


model_input = enc_in
model_output = decoder(z)
v_autoencoder = Model(model_input, model_output)
######################

def vae_r_loss(T1_input, model_output):
  r_loss = K.mean(K.square(T1_input - model_output), axis = [1,2,3])
  return r_loss_factor * r_loss


def vae_kl_loss(T1_input, model_output):
  kl_loss = -0.5 * K.sum(1 + log_variance - K.square(mu) - K.exp(log_variance), axis = 1)
  return kl_loss


def vae_loss(T1_input, model_output):
  r_loss = vae_r_loss(T1_input, model_output)
  kl_loss = vae_kl_loss(T1_input, model_output)
  return r_loss + kl_loss

learning_rate=0.001
r_loss_factor = 500

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate)

v_autoencoder.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss = vae_loss, metrics = [vae_r_loss, vae_kl_loss])
v_autoencoder.summary()
```

But when I try to train the model:

```
history = v_autoencoder.fit(T1_input, T1_input, epochs=10, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: You are passing KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='Placeholder:0', description="created by layer 'tf.cast_4'"), an intermediate Keras symbolic input/output, to a TF API that does not allow registering custom dispatchers, such as `tf.cond`, `tf.function`, gradient tapes, or `tf.map_fn`. Keras Functional model construction only supports TF API calls that *do* support dispatching, such as `tf.math.add` or `tf.reshape`. Other APIs cannot be called directly on symbolic Kerasinputs/outputs. You can work around this limitation by putting the operation in a custom Keras layer `call` and calling that layer on this symbolic input/output.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `encoder` and the `decoder` model seem  to disconnected and the `KerasTensor` are not able to flow correctly. Also, the `encoder` returns three tensors `[ mu , variance , z]` whereas the `decoder` only requires `z` as an input.

Replace these lines,

```py
model_input = enc_in
model_output = decoder(z)
v_autoencoder = Model(model_input, model_output)
```

with,

```py
vae_input = Input(shape = input_shape, name="encoder_input")
mu_ , variance_ , z_ = encoder( vae_input )
vae_output = decoder( z_ )
v_autoencoder = Model( vae_input , [vae_output , mu_ , variance_] )
```

So, basically, the model will now output `mu_` and `variance_` which are the outputs of the encoder, and are required for `vae_kl_loss`. Earlier, you were using these `KerasTensor` directly in `vae_kl_loss` and hence you got the error.

Remove the `axis` argument from `vae_kl_loss`,

```py
def vae_kl_loss( mu , log_variance ):
  kl_loss = -0.5 * K.sum(1 + log_variance - K.square(mu) - K.exp(log_variance))
  return kl_loss
```

Pass `mu` and `variance` to `vae_kl_loss`,

```py
def vae_loss(T1_input, model_output):
  mu = model_output[ 1 ]
  variance = model_output[ 2 ]
  vae_output = model_output[ 0 ]
  r_loss = vae_r_loss(T1_input, vae_output )
  kl_loss = vae_kl_loss( mu , variance )
  return r_loss + kl_loss
```

---

Modified code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, BatchNormalization, Conv3D, Dense, Flatten, Lambda, Reshape, UpSampling3D
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l2
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

## Functional API

input_shape = (32, 32, 32, 1)
z_dim = 3000 

###########  Encoder  ############

enc_in = Input(shape = input_shape, name="encoder_input")

enc_conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(filters=8, kernel_size=5, strides=(1,1,1), padding='same', activation="ReLU", kernel_initializer="he_uniform", name="conv_1")(enc_in)  
max1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=(2,2,2), strides=(2,2,2), padding='valid', name="max_pool_1")(enc_conv1) 

enc_conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation="ReLU", kernel_initializer="he_uniform", name="conv_2")(max1)
max2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=2, name="max_pool_2")(enc_conv2)

enc_fc1 = Dense(units = 512, kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform', activation = 'ReLU')(Flatten()(max2))
   
mu = Dense(units = z_dim, kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform', activation = None, name="mu")(enc_fc1)
   
log_variance = Dense(units = z_dim, kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform', activation = None, name="log_variance")(enc_fc1)   

def sampling(args):
    mu, log_variance = args
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=K.shape(mu), mean= 0., stddev= 1.)
    return mu + K.exp(0.5 * log_variance) * epsilon

z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape = (z_dim, ), name="z")([mu, log_variance]) 

encoder = Model(enc_in, [mu, log_variance, z], name="encoder")


##########  Decoder  ############

dec_in = Input(shape = (z_dim, ), name="decoder_input")

dec_fc1 = Dense(units = 512, kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform', activation = 'ReLU')(dec_in)
dec_unflatten = Reshape(target_shape = (8,8,8,1))(dec_fc1)

dec_conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation="ReLU", kernel_initializer="he_uniform", name="deconv_1")(dec_unflatten)
ups1 = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling3D(size=(2, 2, 2), name="ups_1")(dec_conv1)

dec_conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation="ReLU", kernel_initializer="he_uniform", name="deconv_2")(ups1)
ups2 = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling3D(size=(2, 2, 2), name="ups_2")(dec_conv2)

dec_conv4 = Conv3D(filters = 1, kernel_size = (3, 3, 3), padding = 'same', activation="ReLU", kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform', name='decorder_output')(ups2)

decoder = Model(dec_in, dec_conv4, name="decoder")

vae_input = Input(shape = input_shape, name="encoder_input")
mu_ , variance_ , z_ = encoder( vae_input )
vae_output = decoder( z_ )
v_autoencoder = Model( vae_input , [vae_output , mu_ , variance_] )
######################

def vae_r_loss(T1_input, model_output):
  r_loss = K.mean(K.square(T1_input - model_output), axis = [1,2,3])
  return r_loss_factor * r_loss


def vae_kl_loss( mu , log_variance ):
  kl_loss = -0.5 * K.sum(1 + log_variance - K.square(mu) - K.exp(log_variance))
  return kl_loss


def vae_loss(T1_input, model_output):
  mu = model_output[ 1 ]
  variance = model_output[ 2 ]
  vae_output = model_output[ 0 ]
  r_loss = vae_r_loss(T1_input, vae_output )
  kl_loss = vae_kl_loss( mu , variance )
  return r_loss + kl_loss

learning_rate=0.001
r_loss_factor = 500

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate)

v_autoencoder.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss = vae_loss, metrics = [vae_r_loss, vae_kl_loss])
v_autoencoder.summary()
```

Comment: Thanks!! I fixed what you said, know I'm getting a different error when running the .fit(). The error says: InvalidArgumentError:  required broadcastable shapes
  [[node sub_6
 (defined at <ipython-input-17-8d046d87780d>:8)
]] [Op:__inference_train_function_7080]
Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node sub_6:
In[0] IteratorGetNext (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:866) 
In[1] model/encoder/log_variance/BiasAdd (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/core/dense.py:210)

Comment: Do you have an idea what could be happening? I'll appreciate some help!

Comment: I think the problem is in how the v_autoencoder was defined: "v_autoencoder = Model( vae_input , [vae_output , mu_ , variance_] )" it should be "v_autoencoder = Model(vae_input, vae_output)"